# Continuity of distance difference in $\mathbb{R}^m$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ be continuous, and define $g:\mathbb{R}^{m}\times\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $g(x,y)=|f(x)-f(y)|$. Is $g$ necessarily continuous on $\mathbb{R}^m\times \mathbb{R}^m$? (Here we use the Euclidean metric for all spaces, and view $\mathbb{R}^{m}\times\mathbb{R}^m$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{2m}$.)

I think $g$ should be continuous. We must prove that for any $(x,y)$ and any $\varepsilon$, there exists $\delta$ such that whenever $d((x,y),(z,w))<\delta$, it is true that $$||f(x)-f(y)|-|f(z)-f(w)||<\varepsilon.$$

Suppose that $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_m)$ and similarly for $y,z,w$. We have \begin{align}d((x,y),(z,w)) &= \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^m(x_i-z_i)^2+\sum_{i=1}^m(y_i-w_i)^2} \\&\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^m(x_i-z_i)^2}+\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^m(y_i-w_i)^2}\right) \\&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(d(x,z)+d(y,w)).\end{align}

So $d(x,z)+d(y,w)\leq \sqrt2\delta$. How can we relate this to $||f(x)-f(y)|-|f(z)-f(w)||$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: use

$$|g(x,y)-g(z,w)|=|~\| f(x)-f(y)\|-\|f(z)-f(w)\|~ |\leq \| f(x)-f(y)\|+ \|f(z)-f(w)\|,  $$

and use continuity of $f$.

Comment: Thanks, I think we need in fact $$|~\| f(x)-f(y)\|-\|f(z)-f(w)\|~ |\leq \| f(x)-f(z)\|+ \|f(y)-f(w)\|$$. This can be proved, but less obviously!